# Bootstrap Daterangepicker: range between months and year only

Tags: javascript, html, css, daterangepicker

I'm using this [pluggin daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) but I want to be able to choose only the year and month, keeping the dropdown layout. I've searched for solutions but the only ones I found had the year and month in a select box...Is it possible to achieve this? The layout I pretend looks like this:[image]

This the code im using for testing:

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
          <div class=" col text-center">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

            </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
      .demo { position: relative; }
      .demo i {
        position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 24px; top: auto; cursor: pointer;
      }
      </style>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
        });
       </script>
```

Comment: At this point it might be easier to craft your own month/year picker than to try to hack that one.

Comment: so there's no easy solution for this pluggin, like changing it in the options?

Comment: no, I checked the documentation, there's no option to not ask for the day